# Loop repeated data ini a string with Golang

Tags: go

I have a string like this

```
xx5645645yyxx9879869yyxx3879870977yy
```

Want to get result like following with loop

```
xx5645645yy
xx9879869yy
xx3879870977yy
```

I have no idea to do it, any kind of help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: from what you said, I guess you want to change `yyxx` to `yy\nxx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the strings.Split() function and split on "xx", then prepend "xx" back to each of the split substrings in the loop:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "xx5645645yyxx9879869yyxx3879870977yy"
    items := strings.Split(s, "xx")[1:]  // [1:] to skip the first, empty, item
    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Println("xx" + item)
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
xx5645645yy
xx9879869yy
xx3879870977yy
```